# Web texts & links not displaying properly on macOS browsers

Tags: html, css, web, font-face, webfonts

I am developing a website using wordpress (creating a custom wordpress template) and I have an issue displaying text on browsers running on macOS systems.  These include Safari, Chrome, Firefox...
If you have a Mac you can check it out yourself at http://2c.ggcc.upc.edu.

Depending on which of them, the result is different. On Chrome, the text is displayed but links are not functional.  If we have a look at elements inspector this is what we have:
[image: li element chrome]

In this example I have a menu element selected `<li>`, and we can see the text is displayed a bit above where it should be.  If we now have a look at the `<a>` element, we can see it has no height and therefore it doesn't work properly. (You can not activate it).

[image: a element chrome]

Now let's switch to Safari. On safari the text isn't even displayed, and the links are neither functional.

[image: a element safari]

In this case the `<a>` element hasn't got height, either.

This is not an issue with links only, because some of the body text is neither displayed on safari.

After a bit research I've came to the conclusion that's an issue with the font face I am using, because all these problems are solved if we disable the rule that sets the font-family to 'DIN'.
Currently, I am including my fonts to the website using css:

```css
@font-face {
    font-family: DIN;
    src: url(font/DINRegular.ttf);
    font-weight: normal;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried adding `display: inline-block` to the CSS for the `<a>` tag, or it's parent? It should stop it having zero height/width without effecting the layout.  You can vertically center the text by making the `line-height` attribute of the element equal to the `height` of it's parent.

Comment: @BrianPeacock As I said, it's not a problem with the `<a>` elements only.  Though setting the `inline-block` would solve it for a moment, it is not the solution I am looking for.

Comment: If I check out your link everything works fine on Chrome, Firefox and Safari on OSX Sierra. No displacement, and links are clickable.

Comment: @RoelN Yes, I worked it out yesterday and I forgot to post the solution. My fault.